# how to get sequence of user interaction with android device?

Tags: android, device, interaction

After many sites searched and googling,

I can't find anything for my problem. 
I want to capture the sequence of user interactions on android device. Starting from when the device is powered ON. And one more thing is that I'm not talking about the user event on UI of any application. It's for whole device UI interactions. And if any tools are available then please let me know about it. I didn't get anything about this. Any help or suggestion is well appreciate.

Comment: Give an example of what you want as the output.

Comment: Then is is not possible. Unless you make your own firmware or write a LogCat parser lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, except perhaps via modified firmware, for obvious security and privacy reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure at what extent it will help you to achive your goal but the best way I know is that:

1. You need to implement `Broadcastreceiver` for every action like action `android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"` when your device starts, similarly you need to use all the action which will notify you in your receiver.
2. You can run a service where you can check which app is running for your record. For this you need to fetch installed app list.